JqxGrid delay in React when rendering
import {
    useEffect,
    useRef,
    useState,
    useMemo,
    useCallback,
    lazy,
    Suspense,
  } from "react";
  import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
  import { Modal, Radio } from "antd";
  import { jqx } from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxtreegrid";
  import axios from "axios";
  import loadingGif from "../../../assets/Loading.gif";
  
  const JqxGrid = lazy(() =>
    import("jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxgrid")
  );
  const JqxTreeGrid = lazy(() =>
    import("jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxtreegrid")
  );
  
  const ListUI = ({
    genoString,
    setGenoString,
    showGenoList,
    setShowGenoList,
  }) => {
    const { serverDetails } = useSelector((state) => state.serverDetails);
    const [dataAdapter, setDataAdapter] = useState(null);
    const [dataAdapter2, setDataAdapter2] = useState(null);
    const [showRecent, setShowRecent] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const ref2 = useRef(null);
  
    const fetchData = useCallback(
      async (url, method, headers = {}, data = null) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const response = await axios({ url, method, headers, data });
          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
          if (typeof DisplayError !== "undefined") {
            DisplayError({ message: error.message }, "#divError");
          }
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      },
      []
    );
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (showGenoList) {
        const baseUrl =
          window.location.protocol === "http:"
            ? serverDetails.internalServerUrl ?? ""
            : serverDetails.ServerUrl ?? "";
  
        if (showRecent) {
          if (!dataAdapter2) {
            fetchData(
              `${baseUrl}/endpointForGRid`,
              "POST",
              {
               
                "Content-Type": "application/json",

              }
            ).then((data) => {
              if (data) {
                const source = {
                  datatype: "json",
                  type: "POST",
                  datafields: [
                    { name: "objectid", map: "objectid", type: "int" },
                    { name: "objectname", map: "objectname", type: "string" },
                  ],
                  id: "objectid",
                  localdata: data.GetRecentlistDetails,
                };
                setDataAdapter2(new jqx.dataAdapter(source));
              }
            });
          }
        } else {
          if (!dataAdapter) {
            fetchData(
              `${baseUrl}/endpointforTreegrid`,
              "GET",
              {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",

              }
            ).then((data) => {
              if (data) {
                const source = {
                  datatype: "json",
                  datafields: [
                    { name: "GenoKey", type: "int" },
                    { name: "ParentGenoKey", type: "int" },                
                    { name: "GenealogyCombination", type: "string" },
                  ],
                  hierarchy: {
                    keyDataField: { name: "GenoKey" },
                    parentDataField: { name: "ParentGenoKey" },
                  },
                  id: "GenoKey",
                  localdata: data,
                };
                setDataAdapter(new jqx.dataAdapter(source));
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }, [showGenoList, showRecent, serverDetails, fetchData, dataAdapter2, dataAdapter]);
  
      const columns = useMemo(
      () => [
        { text: "", dataField: "GenoKey", hidden: true },
        { text: "", dataField: "ParentGenoKey", hidden: true },
        { text: "Geno string", dataField: "GenealogyCombination" },
      ],
      []
    );
  
    const columns2 = useMemo(
      () => [
        { text: "", dataField: "objectid", hidden: true },
        { text: "", dataField: "objectname", width: "100%" },
      ],
      []
    );
  
    const handleOk = () => {
      const index = ref.current?.getselectedrowindex();
      if (index !== undefined) {
        setGenoString(ref.current?.getrowdata(index)?.GenealogyString);
        setShowGenoList(false);
      }
    };
  
    const handleCancel = () => setShowGenoList(false);
  
    return (
      <Modal
        title="List UI"
        open={showGenoList}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        width={450}
        centered
        style={{ height: 400 }}
        okButtonProps={{
          style: {
            backgroundColor: typeof c1 !== "undefined" ? c1 : "#184e54",
            color: typeof p3 !== "undefined" ? p3 : "white",
          },
        }}
        cancelButtonProps={{
          style: {
            backgroundColor: typeof c1 !== "undefined" ? c1 : "#184e54",
            color: typeof p3 !== "undefined" ? p3 : "white",
          },
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <Radio.Group
            name="radiogroup"
            defaultValue={1}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const value = e.target.value;
              setShowRecent(value === 2);
              setLoading(true);
            }}
          >
            <Radio value={1}>TreeGrid</Radio>
            <Radio value={2}>Grid</Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
          <div id="jqxtreeGridGenealogySel">
            <div
              style={{
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                height: "100%",
                zIndex: 999,
                display: loading ? "flex" : "none",
              }}
            >
              <img src={loadingGif} alt="Loading..." />
            </div>
  
            {dataAdapter2 && (
              <Suspense
                fallback={
                  <div
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      height: "100%",
                      zIndex: 999,
                      display: "flex",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={loadingGif} alt="Loading..." />
                  </div>
                }
              >
                <JqxGrid
                  ref={ref2}
                  width={"100%"}
                  showheader={false}
                  height={"350px"}
                  source={dataAdapter2}
                  columns={columns2}
                  enabletooltips={true}
                  editable={false}
                  style={{ display: showRecent ? "block" : "none" }}
                  selectionmode="singlerow"
                  theme="material"
                  onBindingcomplete={() => setLoading(false)}
                  ready={() => setLoading(false)}
                />
              </Suspense>
            )}
            {dataAdapter && (
              <Suspense
                fallback={
                  <div
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      height: "100%",
                      zIndex: 999,
                      display: "flex",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={loadingGif} alt="Loading..." />
                  </div>
                }
              >
                <JqxTreeGrid
                  ref={ref}
                  width={"100%"}
                  showHeader={false}
                  height={"350px"}
                  source={dataAdapter}
                  style={{ display: !showRecent ? "block" : "none" }}
                  columns={columns}
                  enabletooltips={true}
                  editable={false}
                  selectionmode="singlerow"
                  theme="material"
                  onBindingcomplete={() => setLoading(false)}
                  ready={() => setLoading(false)}
                />
              </Suspense>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  };
  
  export default ListUI;
  
  
 


I'm experiencing an issue with rendering delays. When I click a radio button, the change event triggers and the JqxGrid updates, but there's a noticeable delay in the radio button's selection state updating— the clicked radio button shows as selected only after a delay.
Is there a way to address this delay? Additionally, any way to show a loading indicator while the JqxGrid or Tree Grid is rendering?
